How to tag words that not include one specific symbol in Spacy?
I'm trying to tag one word in Spacy using regex, but I want to add one condition: it can't contain symbol '/' in any place inside. My code looks like this:
[{'lower': {"regex": "^.*(word).*?"}}]

I tried using ^ to exclude this but It didn't work.
So examples:

'subwordw' tagged: 'subword'
'subword/w' tagged nothing


try this:
{'lower': {'REGEX': "^([^\/]*word[^\/]*)$"}}
